# overriding the initializer of my custom UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, initialization, overriding

this might be a stupid question, and I might kick myself, when I read the solution, but I am currenly stumped.

I have a custom `UIView` subclass:

```
let viewA: UIView = {...}
let viewB: UIView = {...}
let viewC: UIView = {...}
var subviews: [UIView]

class MyView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init() {
      subviews = [viewA, viewB, viewC]
      super.init(frame: .zero)
      abc123(true)
    }

    func abc123(_ cols: Bool) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Now I want to make a slightly modified version of `myView`, but want to keep most of the logic. So a little later in the file I add:

```
class myAltView: MyView {

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override init() {
    subviews = [viewA, viewC]
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    abc123(false)
  }

}
```

The error is obviously in the `super.init(frame: .zero)` of the subclass. 
It won't work, since the super doesn't have an implementation for that. 
I can't call `super.super.init(frame: .zero)`, so how would I go about solving this?

So I then started to rework the "parent class" to contain an `convenience init()` and an `init(subview: [UIView], cols: Bool)`, but again I was not able to successfully override the `convenience init` in the subclass it wanted me to call `self.init` which I was exactly trying to avoid defining in the subclass to avoid redundant code.

This should be easier, but I can't seem to think of the solution. 
Can anyone shed a little light onto this problem...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `init(frame:)` in your superclass and simply call `super`'s implementation from it, hence not changing its behaviour, the issue is resolved.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    init() {
        subviews = [viewA, viewB, viewC]
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        abc123(true)
    }

    func abc123(_ cols: Bool) {}

}
```

Comment: yep - this worked, just had to give `var subviews` a default value and move the line below `super.init` Thanks!